# How do you indicate that a second number for month and day are optional in a single statement?

Tags: forms, dates, formatting

For instance, these are all acceptable in a MM/DD/YYYY format:

- 06/02/2014
- 06/2/2014
- 6/02/2014
- 6/2/2014

Here is what I have at the moment. However, I feel that users might not catch on to what I mean by it:

[image: field]

Is there a way, in a short space like that, to tell the user what I'm trying to?

Comment: Convention is M/d/yyyy - number of appearances of character signifies minimal number of digits permitted.

Comment: Also, either use ISO standard yyyy-MM-dd or use user's machine settings to determine format e.g. European convention dd/MM/yyyy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to. Just show M/d/yyyy. If a user chooses to enter or paste a date with leading zeros then you could show a tick next to the field if it is a valid date.

Most users will use the date picker anyway, and +1 to picking up the users machine settings for format.